# Audio recording and playback in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, avfoundation, core-audio, voip, audio-recording

I want to develop a VOIP application on Mac OS X.The first,I search for some audio APIs on Mac OS X.
Then I found these APIs(or Framework) have the audio capture and playback capabilities:

1.Audio Queues(In the Core Audio Framework of Mac OS X)

2.Audio Units(In the Core Audio Framework of Mac OS X)

3.AVFoundation Framework

4.QTKit Framework

5.....(some APIs that I didn't found)

I'm a noob on Mac OS X ,I don't know which APIs(or framework) is more suitable for developing a VOIP application , Can someone give some suggestion ?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Have you have any solutions or example for recording and playback on Mac. I try the audio unit but it only work fine when I using headphone. Still very noise when I try without the headphone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VOIP, low latency is important for usability.  The Audio Unit API will allow your app the lowest latency audio.  AVFoundation and Audio Queues are built on top of Audio Units.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.The Audio Unit seem to be the best choice.